# How do I get the name of the current terminal in Vim?

Tags: vimrc, terminal, microsoft-windows

I'm currently running Vim in Windows 10. I want to specify in my config file certain settings for when I'm running Vim in Cmder, different settings when I'm running Vim in Alacritty, etc.

When in Cmder, if I run `echo &term` I get `win32`, and when I run `echo $term` I get `cygwin`. What's the difference between `$term` and `&term`, and are these the only ways I can access the name of the terminal? Are one of those correct? The shell I'm running in Cmder is cmd with Cmder's clink configurations.

Comment: Are you running `echo $term` or `echo $TERM`? The `$` variables are the ones coming from the environment, so you should be able to find/inspect them there as well...

Comment: See also [`:help 'term'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27term%27), you'll see how it defaults to `win32` on Windows...

Comment: @filbranden I'm running `echo $term` but `echo $TERM` gives the same thing. Is there a way to get it to recognize that I'm running Cmder?

Comment: Do you have environment variables `$CMDER_ROOT` or `$ConEmuDir` that you can perhaps use for detection? (I'm just going by the website... I haven't really used Cmder or ConEmu, haven't used a Windows system in quite while...)

Comment: Perhaps there are better alternative than setting specific option for Cmder. Which settings do you want to customize for Cmder?

Comment: @filbranden Yep, this seems to be the way to do it.

Comment: @jdhao One example is colorschemes. Some look atrocious on Cmder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the two variables:

- `$term` is a variable from the environment. When you are on the terminal (without opening Vim), `echo $term` should echo the same as `:echo $term` from inside Vim. (I'm a little bit surprised that it is not upper case, like `$TERM`.)
- `&term` represents the option `term` (see `:h 'term'`). So the output from `:echo &term` is the same as the output from `:set term?`.

If you need some information about the world outside of Vim you can check environment variables (like `$TERM`).

In both of your terminal run the command `set` to list all environment variables with their values and find a variable that has a different value per terminal. Or a variable that is set in one terminal, but not the other.

By just looking at the Cmder web sites I *guess* it could be something like this:

```
if $CMDER_ROOT != ''
   " do CMDER stuff here
else
   " do other stuff here
fi
```

Comment: I wouldnt be surprised in windows env variables were case insensitive *rolls eyes*

Comment: This works! Thanks so much! It is indeed `$CMDER_ROOT`.

Answer (score 0):

In my macOS system, the unique name of the terminal program is set in environment variable `TERM_PROGRAM`. Apple's inbuilt Terminal, iTerm2, WezTerm return sensible unique names that correctly identify them. As of writing this, Alcritty does not set it to any value, and Kitty terminal emulator returns wrong name "Apple_Terminal".

Run `echo $TERM_PROGRAM` in your system to see if it works there as well.